# How to filter value in a card based on another chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have Slicer `InsurType`, Pie Chart `Premium by Division` and Card that represents `Budget`
On a picture below all InsurType are selected and Budget shows correct amount (101.4M).

[image]

If I choose parameter on a slicer, then the Budget value also represents correct amount (picture 2).

[image]

But now, if I click and choose value on a pie chart - then the Budget value will not be effected. 
I tried to change Edit Interaction but still - no effect.

So why the Budget value is not filtered by Pie Chart selection?

[image]

I am assuming its something to do with relationship that have `"BudgetDate"` table and `"Divisions"`

[image]

Divisions table looks like this:

[image]

Any advise how should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way for the `Premiums` table to affect the `BudgetData` table based on your diagram (look at the way the arrows are pointing).

I'd suggest editing the relationship to allow two directional filtering by changing the "Cross filter direction" from "Single" to "Both".

[image: Filter Direction]